# How to extract individual letters from image with PyTesseract?

Tags: python, ocr, opencv, python-tesseract

I am teaching myself python and am trying to make a simple program to recognize letters from an image. The letters are not in sentence or paragraph form. I am trying to do this using cv2 + pytesseract for detection, but I just can't seem to get it to work reliably. I am beginning to suspect I am using the wrong tool for the job but I can't find anything else to help me.

This is my reference image with the letters I want to extract:

[image]

Ideally I would like the letter and also the coordinates of each letter (bounding box). I've been able to apply a mask and threshold to the image to get this:

[image]

But what I am stuck on is Pytesseract being unable to reliably give me the letters individually or even correctly. Here is my console output...

```
$ py main.py --image test.png
D
C UL
UO
```

The code I am using is simply taking the black and white text image and running it through pytesseract. I've tried playing around with the `--psm` flag but because the text is in an odd shape, I haven't had much luck.

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename), config='-l eng --psm 11')
os.remove(filename)
print(text)
```

Comment: What's wrong? And what kind of help are you expecting if we can't see your code?

Comment: As my console shows, the output is not correct. I will add my code however it is not very significant. What I am hoping for is a pointer in the right direction of what I should be doing here. My experience with this is not very deep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can segment and process each letter one by one. You can look the detail in my code.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread("xO6JI.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

items = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = items[0] if len(items) == 2 else items[1]

img_contour = img.copy()
for i in range(len(contours)):
    area = cv2.contourArea(contours[i])
    if 100 < area < 10000:
        cv2.drawContours(img_contour, contours, i, (0, 0, 255), 2)

detected = ""
for c in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    ratio = h/w
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    base = np.ones(thresh.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    if ratio > 0.9 and 100 < area < 10000:
        base[y:y+h, x:x+w] = thresh[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        segment = cv2.bitwise_not(base)

        custom_config = r'-l eng --oem 3 --psm 10 -c tessedit_char_whitelist="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" '
        c = pytesseract.image_to_string(segment, config=custom_config)
        print(c)
        detected = detected + c
        cv2.imshow("segment", segment)
        cv2.waitKey(0)

print("detected: " + detected)

cv2.imshow("img_contour", img_contour)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The result

```
U
O
L
C
D
detected: UOLCD
```

Comment: This is great. I was doing a lot more research last night and thought contours may be in the solution. Your code does not show how you are getting the contours though. Would you mind adding that in? Specifically, `contours` is not defined.

Comment: I am sorry. I forgot to copy the code. I have fixed it.

Comment: Thank you! This is working and it gives me something with good understanding to work off of for to get the bounds.